# GeoDMS, is there example code to convert csv files directly to fss files?

Tags: geodms

I am creating a GeoDMS configuration that reads GTFS files (which are stored in csv format), constructs a spatiotemporally explicit network out of those files, and then computes OD traveltime matrices based on that network.

I am currently reading the csv files using the StorageType = "gdal.grid" property, which is useful because in that manner I do not have to specify the length of the csv file a-priori. However, to speed up the computation I would like to convert the raw csv files into GeoDMS-native fss files, as that would significantly speed up the data reading.

However if I am not mistaken, I would need to explicitly define all attributes I would like to store into the fss file, correct? In short, is there any example code out there in which csv files are stored into fss files?

Currently loading the csv files, and storing the intermediate results into a shapefile.. but that is not very elegant. Ideally I get my hands on a function that 'copies' csv files into fss files without having to know cardinality or fieldnames a-priori. If I need to specify all field names that would not be a problem either.

Currently attempting the following very naive, which does not work.

```
Template LoadCsvThroughGDAL {

parameter<File_Structure> inFile;

unit<uint32> Data: StorageName = "= '%DataDir%/_feeds/'+AvailableFeeds/Name[inFeed]+'/'+File_Structure/Name[inFile]+'.csv'", StorageType = "gdal.vect", StorageReadOnly = "True";

unit<uint32> StoreFSS: expr = "Data", StorageName = "= '%DataDir%/_feeds/'+AvailableFeeds/Name[inFeed]+'/fss/'+File_Structure/Name[inFile]+'.fss'";

}
```

Comment: something along the lines having an fss storage holder with `for_each_nedv(SubItem_propvalue(x, 'name'), ...)` , and as `for_each` doesn't allow for unit results: have a domain unit both above the storage holder and inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris,

Hereby a working example for:
1) reading data from a .csv file 
2) writing the data to a .fss file 
 
3) reading the data again from this .fss file 
without having to explicitly configure the attribute names.

```
parameter<string> SourceDir := '%SourceDataDir%/OV/GTFS_20190318';
container write_to_fss
{
   unit<uint32> trip
   : StorageName     = "=SourceDir + '/trips.csv'"
   , StorageType     = "gdal.vect"
   , StorageReadOnly = "True";

   unit<uint32> name := SubItem_PropValues(trip,'name');
   unit<uint32> fssdomain := trip;

   container to_fss := for_each_nedv(name/name, 'trip/' + name/name, fssdomain, string)
   ,    StorageName = "=SourceDir + '/trip.fss'"
   {
      unit<uint32> domain := fssdomain;
   }
}

container readdomain: StorageName = "=SourceDir + '/trip.fss'"
,   StorageReadOnly = "True"
{
    unit<uint32> domain;
}

container trip := for_each_ndv(write_to_fss/name/name, readdomain/domain, string)
, StorageName     = "=SourceDir + '/trip.fss'"
, StorageReadOnly = "True"
{
    unit<uint32> domain;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can remove the last `unit<uint32> domain;`.

Comment: and if you knew that all attributes are numbers, you could convert them to for example `float64` by  `container to_fss := for_each_nedv(name/name, 'float64(trip/' + name/name+')', fssdomain, float64)` and then read them as such.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is very useful! I bump into one issue though. When using a slightly adapted version of the above code i irregularly get hard crashes. The only difference between failure and success that I can identify is whether the domain item is stored in the fss structure. The domain item is not stored consistently in the fss (you would expect a domain.dmsdata file to be generated into all fss structures, correct?). Is there an easy way to ensure consistent storage of the domain item?

Answer (score 0):

If you would take the read domain out of the trip container it should work.

```
parameter<string> SourceDir := '%SourceDataDir%/OV/GTFS_20190318';
container write_to_fss
{
    unit<uint32> trip
    : StorageName     = "=SourceDir + '/trips.csv'"
    , StorageType     = "gdal.vect"
    , StorageReadOnly = "True";

    unit<uint32> name := SubItem_PropValues(trip,'name');
    unit<uint32> fssdomain := trip;

    container to_fss_domain : StorageName = "=SourceDir + '/trip_domain.fss'"
    {
        unit<uint32> domain := fssdomain;
    }

    container to_fss := 
        for_each_nedv(
            name/name
            , 'trip/' + name/name
            , to_fss_domain/domain
            , string
        )
    ,   StorageName = "=SourceDir + '/trip.fss'";
}

container readdomain
:   StorageName = "=SourceDir + '/trip_domain.fss'"
,   StorageReadOnly = "True"
{
    unit<uint32> domain;
}

container trip := 
    for_each_ndv(
        write_to_fss/name/name
        , readdomain/domain
        , string)
,   StorageName     = "=SourceDir + '/trip.fss'"
,   StorageReadOnly = "True"
{
    unit<uint32> domain := readdomain/domain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jip, this does the trick. I just want to note here that in the example above, to_fss_domain/domain are stored to a different file name than the csv fields. This is absolutely necessary to ensure that the domain is stored explicitly, consistently.

Comment: I have set up a set of rules with the FileExists() function to ensure that fss files are stored once, and then read. I did so by referring to the domain unit (to_fss_domain/domain before storage, than readdomain) and data container (to_fss than trip) separately. To ensure that all data is accessible after initial storage, it pays off to set an explicitsuppliers rule that refers to the data container. For example, unit<uint32> boo: expr = "loadcsv/readdomain/domain", ExplicitSuppliers = "loadcsv/trip". This ensures that, when no fss files are generated, all the fields in to_fss are stored.